# Tor hidden service not able to connect

Tags: onion-services

I just installed tor on a fresh ubuntu box, I've configured the hidden services part of the `torrc` file as follows:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 90 127.0.0.1:90
```

I've got apache successfully running on port 90 and have verified it with a web browser.

Now I've restarted tor by doing `service tor reload` and looked at the log file located at `/var/log/tor/log` and these are the results:

```
Jun 23 00:48:07.000 [notice] Tor 0.2.4.20 (git-0d50b03673670de6) opening new log file.
Jun 23 01:02:31.000 [notice] Received reload signal (hup). Reloading config and resetting internal state.
Jun 23 01:02:31.000 [notice] Read configuration file "/usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc".
Jun 23 01:02:31.000 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Jun 23 01:02:31.000 [notice] Tor 0.2.4.20 (git-0d50b03673670de6) opening log file.
```

And that's it. It hasn't said anything else for about 20 minutes. I've navigated to `/var/lib/tor/hidden_service/` to verify that it created a private key and a hostname and it did. Not sure what's going on.

Edit: I did a hard stop on the service and then a hard start, this is what is in the log file now:

```
Jun 23 01:28:32.000 [notice] Tor 0.2.4.20 (git-0d50b03673670de6) opening log file.
Jun 23 01:28:32.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Jun 23 01:28:32.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Jun 23 01:28:32.000 [warn] OpenSSL version from headers does not match the version we're running with. If you get weird crashes, that might be why. (Compiled with 1000105f: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013; running with 1000106f: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014).
Jun 23 01:28:32.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server.
Jun 23 01:28:32.000 [notice] We now have enough directory information to build circuits.
Jun 23 01:28:32.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 80%: Connecting to the Tor network.
Jun 23 01:28:33.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 85%: Finishing handshake with first hop.
Jun 23 01:28:34.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 90%: Establishing a Tor circuit.
Jun 23 01:28:35.000 [warn] Received http status code 404 ("Not found") from server 'x.x.x.x:9001' while fetching "/tor/keys/fp/27B6B5996C42xxxxA5C95488AA5BCxxxxCC86956".
Jun 23 01:28:35.000 [notice] Tor has successfully opened a circuit. Looks like client functionality is working.
Jun 23 01:28:35.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 100%: Done.
```

What does that 404 mean?

Answer (score 0):

To run a hidden service takes a bit of time. When you fire up the hidden service for the first time, you need to send your information to (I believe) 6 introduction points along with letting the HSDir authorities know that you exist.

I don't believe that the 404 is related to your problem. It refers to a connection attempt to download the keys for a certain fingerprint from a directory authority's web service. But the logs show that a subsequent attempt to connect worked.

If you've waited more than a few hours to try and connect to your hidden service, you can delete the cached files inside of the tor directory to force it to re-download the consensus.